# I can't receive string that I have sent through nrf correctly

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, string, nrf24l01+, pointer

I'm using arduino uno and nrf24l01. to monitor sensor data.
But this is the message that master receives:

> ⸮

this is my slave code.

```
void monitoring() {
    delay(10);
    radio.stopListening();
    int soilMoisture = analogRead(A5);
    int light = analogRead(A4);
    float temp = analogRead(A3);
    temp = temp * 0.48828125;
    int ltemp = int(temp);
    String message = String(soilMoisture) + "," + String(light) + "," +    String(ltemp);
    Serial.println(message);
    delay(200);
    radio.write(&message, sizeof(message));
    delay(50);
    radio.startListening();
    delay(10);
}
```

and here is my master code.

```
while (1) {
    if (radio.available()) {
      char message[32] = "";
      radio.read(&message, sizeof(message));
      delay(500);
      Serial.println(message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the & in the master code line, change

```
 radio.read(message, sizeof(message));
```

to

```
radio.read(message, sizeof(message));
```

`message` is an array, so either you should pass the address of the first character (`&message[0]`), or simply pass `message`.

Another problem is sending a String in the slave code (using type `String`). It's better not to use this type anyway, but you probably have to convert it to a character array of the same type as in the master code.

You can use the function `StringToCharArray` for that, see [StringToCharArray](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.StringToCharArray).

Comment: Thank you very much